# Securing my NTP configuration

Tags: configuration, ntp, restrictions

Need some assistance configuring my ntp.conf file for my primary NTP server.

Does my configuration accomplish the following:

- Prevent the servers being polled from changing my configuration?
- Allow my peer to sync up?
- Allow clients to get time from my server?

Am I missing any further restrictions, options, etc?

```
# Servers
server time.example.com iburst
server time.example.net
server time.example.org
peer   ntp2.mydomain.com

# Restrictions
# Servers
restrict time.example.com kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict time.example.net kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict time.example.org kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

# Peers
restrict ntp2.mydomain.com 

# Clients
restrict 1.1.1.1 nomodify notrap
restrict 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 nomodify notrap

# Loopback
restrict 127.0.0.1

# Deny rest
restrict default ignore
restrict -6 default ignore
```

I also plan to modify iptables to only allow inbound connections from my 10.0.0.0/8 subnet and specific public hosted servers.

The other question I had was, could I remove the `nopeer` from the time.example.xxx hosts since they are servers and not peers? Or is it still required?